# Is the BlueZ bluetooth library for C one of the white-listed API's for Google's Native-Client SDK?

Tags: c++, c, google-chrome, bluetooth, bluez

I'd like to use both Google's Native-client API and BlueZ for a senior design project but, I can't figure out if BlueZ is compatible the Native Client SDK. Does the full set of white-listed APIs include this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain if bluetooth APIs in general are white-listed for Android Native Client apps, but even if they are, there are not going to be native BlueZ APIs available on all devices or versions.

As indicated by Google (https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth.html) as of JB 4.2 the native bluetooth stack is BlueDroid, which is based on Broadcom's stack. Before that time BlueZ was the default stack, but was replaced by some vendors with their own.

It may still be possible to install BlueZ on your newer OS device if it is rooted, but you cannot at all be certain the underlying stack on any random device will be BlueZ or BlueDroid, so if developing an app for distribution you would need to limit yourself to official APIs that Android provides (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), or maybe implement on each stack and detect at runtime what stack to use, assuming what you want to do is even possible with BlueDroid.